# access element of a datagriview after a double click

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (c#). I would like to have an access to every member of the selected row after a double click.

Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook up the `CellDoubleClick` event of the data grid. The `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` contains the row and column that was clicked. If the row index is -1 the header was clicked.

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        // header was clicked
    }
    else
    {
        // data row was clicked, can access the row contents like this
        var row = MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var cell = row[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
   {

   }
}
```